# Trying to look up how many times a user has been muted in discord.js using mongdb

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

My full code: http://hatebin.com/zetpnqyqus

Basically, everytime a user gets muted they get put onto the database with their ID legnth of mute and time of mute, im trying to then, when someone is muted lookup on the database to see how many times they are on the database then either console.log that or add it to the mute message.

Should work minimal code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ms = require("ms");
const fs = require("fs");
const mute = require("../models/mutes.js");
 //mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/ReportsMutes", { useNewUrlParser: true });
 const moment = require ('moment')






module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/ReportsMutes", function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
      console.log("We are connected");
    }
  });


    let tomute = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
    if(!tomute) return message.reply("Gimmie a user to mute or i mute u");

    if(message.member.roles.find(r=> r.name === "Mod")){

    // if(tomute.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("U dont have perms innit");
    let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "muted");

  let time = message.createdAt
         //finding the user in database


    //start of create role

    if(!muterole){
      try{
        muterole = await message.guild.createRole({
          name: "muted",
          color: "#000000",
          permissions:[]
        })
        message.guild.channels.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
          await channel.overwritePermissions(muterole, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            ADD_REACTIONS: true
          });
        });
      }catch(e){
        console.log(e.stack);
      }
    }
    //end of create role

    let mutetime = args[1];
    if(!mutetime) return message.reply("How long? Hello???");

    await(tomute.addRole(muterole.id));
    message.reply(`<@${tomute.id}> has been muted for ${ms(ms(mutetime))} l8a nerd`);
    let mutechannel = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === "gags-and-bans")
    mutechannel.send(`<@${tomute.id}> has been muted for ${ms(ms(mutetime))} `)

    db.mutes.find({"mUsername" : `${tomute.username}`}).count() 


 mutelegnth = ms(ms(mutetime))
 created = message.createdAt

    setTimeout(function(){
      tomute.removeRole(muterole.id);
      message.channel.send(`<@${tomute.id}> has been unmuted!`); 
    }, ms(mutetime));

    }
    else{
        message.channel.send("Only Mods can mute people, get gud fam");

    }

    const Mute = new mute({
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      mUsername: tomute.user.username,
      legnth: mutelegnth,
      time:  moment(message.createdAt).format('DD YY, h:mm: a')

    });

    Mute.save()
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));




} // closes module.exports
module.exports.help = {
    name: "mute" 
  }


  //they have been muted ${userr} time(s) before!
```

Comment: It would be nice not to link to your code but to create a MCVE which is presented in your question, this may help you: [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
mute.countDocuments({ mUsername: "username" }, function(err, num){
    console.log(`User muted: ${num} times`)
})
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments